# VMWare Player does not save changes in guest operating system

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I have installed VMWare Player in my Windows 7 Ultimate and I have added Ubuntu 12.10 in a virtual machine. The problem is that every time I power off the virtual machine everything is lost. I mean every program I install or folder i save or anything else is lost completely. And when I start the again the virtual machine is like newly installed.

Is there an option to change this (strange) behaviour?

Comment: file..preferences   is yours like mine? http://i.imgur.com/EFLvhGu.png  I wonder if for "when closing a virtual machine" yours was set to power off , when it should be set to suspend. Though i'm sure when I power off a machine and power it on it doesn't reset!

Answer (score 1):

check out your configuration. All configurations are set in the *.vmx file Open yourVirualmachine.vmx with notepad and check the snapshot.action entry. If it's set to snapshot.action = "autoRevert" no changes will be saved. Then change to snapshot.action = "keep" this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

When the VM was created several question were asked about the disk and its behaviour on power down. One of those options is to revert the disk to its previous state.

Please check your config. (Screenshot taken from Vmware workstation 8 since I had that installed)

[image: VMware workstation 8 disk behaviour options]

In your case you probably want 'just power off now'.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the help. It seems that the option 'Snapshots' does not exist in VMWare Player. Maybe it's an option you have to choose when installing the VM. I will try this.

Comment: I dont have it too! mine is 10

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're booting the installation disk image every time and not installing the OS onto a virtual hard drive. That way you're operating live and the changes can't persist.